# Which algorithm for assigning pattern shifts

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm looking for a good algorithm or technic to find the best solution for the following problem. First, I’ll introduce the context and then, the problem.

I work for a company with more than 2000 employees; all of them work with pattern shift, this means that any employee has a pattern which specifies the sequence of workday and free day. We have these patterns:

5-2-5-2 (5 days work, 2 free, 5 days work, 2 free) and so on.

5-2-4-3

5-4-5-3

5-3-5-3

At this moment we have all these patterns and different numbers of start, that is to say, a pattern can start at a certain date at a specific part inside the pattern, for e.g., the pattern 5-4-5-3 has 17 possible starting sequences, this number is a sum of 5+4+5+3 = 17 possible sequences.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_plan

Now the problem,

Every 6 months each employee can change the pattern and start in any sequence number of the pattern.
But we must analyze all the requirements and accept or reject in order to obtain the better combination for the company operation, because we need that every day have the same work force but we understand that this is impossible but the algorithm will help us find a good solution, not perfect.

I was reading about the "[Nurse scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem)" with [Google Or-Tool](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling) but I don’t understand how to set Pattern Sequence to create a solution for this problem. I read some opinions about [GA (genetic algorithms)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) and all of them said that this kind of solution is not good for this kind of problem.

Does anyone have a similar problem? Can someone give me a more accurate example with Google OR-tools than the example in GitHub.

it's not necessary to find a strictly optimal solution; the roster is currently done manual, and I'm pretty sure the result is considerably sub-optimal most of the time.

Comment: I don't know where to start with this. I guess I should start with Welcome to StackOverflow. The problem you have stated here is primarily looking for guidance on where to begin your search for solving this problem. Generally, that type of question is best left for forums or open community discussions. Finding good learning material for Linear programming is not easy but this is not the place for it.

Comment: CPlex, Gurobi and OptimJ are some places to start look into

Comment: Thats very broad. Please show some attempts or detail problems. Also be more clear if you need to schedule 2000 people at once or something smaller. The global constraint "regular" might make this problem much easier.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have a similar problem?

Sounds a lot like [OptaWeb Employee Rostering](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/employeeRostering.html), which is a vertical on top of OptaPlanner, the constraint solver. Take a look at [the source code](http://%20https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering). It's all open source.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be modeled as a MIP model.

Thinking out loud:

Introduce a binary decision variable:

```
δ(i,p) = 1 if pattern i is selected for person p  
         0 otherwise
```

This includes the current pattern (say `i=0`). This would allow the cases:

- an employee does not submit a new pattern (then we only have `i=0` for this employee)
- an employee submits one or more preferable patterns

We have the constraints:

```
sum(i, δ(i,p)) = 1                                    ∀p
sum((i,p), pattern(i,p,t)*δ(i,p)) ≈ requiredlevel(t)  ∀t
δ(i,p) ∈ {0,1}
```

here `pattern(i,p,t)` describes pattern `i`: it is 1 if period t is covered when pattern (i,p) is used and 0 otherwise. Here I use ≈ to indicate "approximately". (This is easily modeled using slacks and possibly penalty terms in the objective).

Now we maximize

```
maximize sum((i,p), weight(i,p) * δ(i,p))
```

where `weight(i,p)` indicates the preference for a pattern (e.g. `weight(0,p)=0` i.e. no bonus points when not selected a newly, preferred pattern).

Something like this should not be too difficult to set up. Of course many refinements are possible. These type of model tend to solve quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

What is the workflow ?

If you have a fixed roster, and one person proposes a new pattern. Just remove this person contribution, test all (17) starting points of the new pattern and score them.

If you can change patterns, or starting points for more than 1 employee, create an integer variable per starting point.  From this starting point, it is easy to compute the persons contribution for each shifted day of the pattern. Then you can optimize quality of service w.r.t. the starting points of each pattern, summing potential contributions per day of the week for each employee.

Is that clear ?